# How to fetch data from a through model in django model forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my model i have:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    # Relational fields
    #more fields
    sports_assigned = models.ManyToManyField('Sport', through="StudentSportAssociation")
```

And my model form like :

```
class UpdateStudentForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateStudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
    sports_assigned = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=SportWithLevel.objects.all(),
                                                     widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Select", is_stacked=False), required=True)
```

The throuth table is :

```
class StudentSportAssociation(AbstractBaseModel):
    """
    Association of student to a sport and his current level in the sport
    """
    sport = models.ForeignKey('Sport')
    level = models.ForeignKey('Level')
    student = models.ForeignKey('StudentProfile', related_name="sports_with_levels")
    # save and all follows
```

Now i need to access the

> StudentSportAssociation

"through" table while accessing the form.
right now it fetches values from the Sport model.
Can anything be done to break this normal way and gets the details from the through table?

Comment: Have you tested `self.instance` ? Also, what you want to do exactly?

Comment: the associated model here is StudentProfile. When i try to use it(StudentProfile) in a form I need to get data in the through table(StudentSportAssociation) via the sports_assigned column in StudentProfile. That is i want to have the data in "sports_with_levels" rather than "sports_assigned" while using the StudentProfile model in my model form UpdateStudentForm.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this section of the django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships.
Especially read the last two examples. They describe how to get the intermediate objects.

To sum it up, you got 2 choices:

1.Get the Intermediate models with a separate query

```
StudentSportAssociation.objects.filter(student=student_profile_instance)
```

2.You query the the many-to-many reverse relationship. In your case:

```
student_profile_instance.sports_with_levels.all()
```

"sports_with_levels" since you defined a related_name if you do not define one it would be:

```
student_profile_instance.studentsportassociation_set.all()
```

Django adds a "_set" to the model name by default.